# MongoDB Query takes too long

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reactjs, flux

**Problem: When creating the first document for a user, query takes too long**

I'm creating some report, of the schema Report. I also have a UserSchema. I create a document in my UI and pass that data to a post request which is this:

```
exports.addSubReport = function(req,res) {

        var id = req.body.masterform;
        var subform = new Report();
        var myDate = Date();
        subform.title = req.body.title;
        subform.date = req.body.date;
        subform.date = myDate;
        subform.owner = req.user;
        subform.body = req.body.body;
        subform.save();
        Report.findById(id, function (err, report) {
          if(err) {
            res.redirect('/404NotFound');
          }
          else {
            report.subreport.push(subform);
            subform.parentReport = report;
            report.save();
          }
        });
        User.findById(req.body.id, function (err, user) {
            user.forms_created.push(subform);
            subform.owner = req.user;
            subform.authors[0] = user.profile.firstName + " " + user.profile.lastName;
            subform.author = user;
            subform.save();
        });

        res.json(req.body);
    };
```

this works fine and creates the object the way I want it to, however after creating the document, I set the state in my UI to 'Wait' until I can recieve the JSON with this new Report I just created. This is the GET request code:

```
exports.allMyReports = function(req, res) {
var id = req.user._id;
        var totalproc = 0;
        var dupe = [];
        Report.find({"author" : id}, function (err, form) {
            dupe = form;

            dupe.forEach(function (person) {

                User.findById(person.author, function (err, user) {
                    if (!err) {
                        person.authors[0] = user.profile.firstName + " " + user.profile.lastName;
                        person.save();
                        totalproc = totalproc + 1;

                    }
                    if (totalproc == dupe.length) {
                        res.json(dupe);
                    }
                }

                );
            });


        });
};
```

However the problem is that on every first report I create for a user, it takes an extremely long time. It's most likely the query of searching for it by author but than I thought well.... if the user has 15 documents already how does it even find all those documents instaneously? I have no idea why it takes so long in this case though and I haven't been able to come up with a solution yet but I think it has to do with how I'm querying.

Here is a sample of how i do it in the UI:

```
_onCreateReport = () => {
  const title = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.title).value;
  const date = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.date).value;
  const body = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.body).value;
  ReportsActions.addNewReport({
        title: title,
        date: date,
        body: body
    });
  ReportsActions.getMyReports();
}
```

I perform the action of adding a new report ('post' request to API), and then getMyReport 'get' request to api for all reports belonging to me, once that returns it shows a new render of 3 buttons, one to view that document, one to view all my documents, one to create another report.

Comment: Does this only happen when creating the first report? or for creating every report?

Comment: Just the first initial report, if there is any  amount of documents > 1 for that user the task is done almost instantaneously.

Comment: Are you saying, do a Report.find({}) where I query all documents then begin to iterate through the returned array for a user? Yea I think so too, I had already started doing that. As for the react part I'm just calling a ajax call (POST request) everything within the addNewReport is the data I am sending for my POST request and I call a GET request somewhere too, but it is asynchronous. Will comment back with results!

Comment: Ok so I optimized it. I was naive to think that querying each document for a user everytime wouldn't be THAT expensive as it scales, but i shouldn't do it like that anyways. Instead what I did was just reuse my query for all reports api, and let the front end handle the rest. In the front end I just iterated through my array and kept the elements that matched with the current users logged in. As for the user creating a document, the data is received a lot faster than before. If you want to submit the comment as your answer Matthew Antolovich I wouldn't mind selecting it as correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did, was request all the documents, and figure it out in the front-end. It reduced the time of the ajax call and I just filtered it out in my front-end which performs quick and doesn't hold the server up.